# Retrieve an access token for Azure ACR using Azure Javascript SDK

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-sdk-js

I have an Azure subscription and I am using Azure Container Registry.
I need to `docker login` to access my repository. This is easily done using the CLIs [[docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli#az-acr-login-with---expose-token):

```
TOKEN=$(az acr login --name <acrName> --expose-token --output tsv --query accessToken)
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io --username 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --password-stdin <<< $TOKEN
```

Is there a way to get this token using the official SDK? Specifically javascript SDK.

I instantiate the ACR client this way, but I don't see a way to retrieve the token. Yet the CLI tool is clearly capable of doing that :)

```
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const client = new ContainerRegistryClient(endpoint, credential);
```

For context, in AWS ECR this is achieved with `GetAuthorizationTokenCommand` command on ECR client [[docs]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/ecr/command/GetAuthorizationTokenCommand/). The response includes the token:

```
{ // GetAuthorizationTokenResponse
  authorizationData: [ // AuthorizationDataList
    { // AuthorizationData
      authorizationToken: "STRING_VALUE",
      expiresAt: new Date("TIMESTAMP"),
      proxyEndpoint: "STRING_VALUE",
    },
  ],
};
```